# Button does not work inside adapter class

Tags: php, android, baseadapter

```
    public class WishlistAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Response.UserinfoEntity> userinfo;
    private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://www.bruhnancel.xyz/" ;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        public void onItemClicked(int position);

    }
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    public WishlistAdapter(Context mContext, List<Response.UserinfoEntity> userinfo) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.userinfo = userinfo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userinfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return userinfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wishlist_row_item, parent, false);
        Response.UserinfoEntity item = (Response.UserinfoEntity) getItem(position);
        TextView feedback_name_voted = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_name_voted);

       // TextView title = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView comment_posted= (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.comment_posted);
        //TextView id = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        final TextView like_total_number= (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.like_total_number);
        ImageView pic = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.latest_promotion_pic);

        Button delete_wishlist = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_wishlist);
        delete_wishlist.setTag(position);
        feedback_name_voted.setText("Name = " +item.getAd_title());
        comment_posted.setText(item.getCom_name());
        like_total_number.setText(item.getAd_id());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getImg_link())
                .into(pic);




        delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DeleteWishlist(like_total_number.getText().toString()).execute();
                // for the better performance remove auto-boxing
                listener.onItemClicked((Integer)v.getTag());
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }


    private class DeleteWishlist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        String  delete;


        public DeleteWishlist( String delete )
        {

            this.delete = delete;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //showProgressDialog("Please wait...", "Your message");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();


            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ad_id", delete));




            try{
                HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "delete_wishlst.php");



                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            {

                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ads successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams(){

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000 * 30);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000*30);
        return httpRequestParams;
    }

    private void showProgressDialog(String title, String message)
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait"); //title

        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading"); // message

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");


    $ad_id = $_POST["ad_id"];




    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE  FROM wish_list WHERE ad_id= ?");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $ad_id);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Error

```
01-22 16:23:46.435 18618-18618/com.example.user.mfpv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.user.mfpv2, PID: 18618
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.user.mfpv2.WishlistAdapter$1.onClick(WishlistAdapter.java:105)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So what i doing nw is i try to send a request to my database by sending a string by using php file.

But it doesnt seem to work. This is the first time i implement this inside an adapter class.

Comment: You should use HttpUrlConnection as HttpClient is deprecated. Secondly what is not working. Have you tried logging any info in your button click listener?

Comment: When i click the button, it should send string (ad_id) and it should delete the selected row of item in mysql. I have test it at normal java class, but when i try to implement it inside adapter class it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use mysql client using the same credentials and run the query as is and check if it is working or no.

Second, change the "s" in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $ad_id);` to "i", since the ID column should be of type integer not string, unless your database differs.

Checkout the PHP manual for more, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

If it is still not working, check that the PHP script is really called, check your web server's access logs, also PHP error logs for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide external interface for the best case.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

   public void onItemClicked(int position);

}
```

and set him to adapter.

```
public class WishlistAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

// code
private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

And use in getView method :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // your code    

        Button delete_wishlist = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_wishlist);
        delete_wishlist.setTag(position);
        // your code
        delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // for the better performance remove auto-boxing
                listener.onItemClicked((Integer)v.getTag());   
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

#### Update

You need set callback to adapter.

```
// in activity or where you create an adapter

WishlistAdapter adapter = new WishlistAdapter(...);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(

    public void onItemClicked(int posisiton) {
        // handle click
    }
));
```

Comment: i follow your step but i get force close. i edited my post please have a look thanks...

Comment: @TomatoJuice what did you have as force close error?

Comment: hii i updated my code, please take a look at my code as it doesnt seem to work when i put new Wishlist(like_total_number.getText()....)

Comment: @TomatoJuice this is more than you ask. The your current question defer from the first.

Comment: alright then i will just open a new question..thanks anyway